# Particle objects interact with fluid simulation

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am new in blender , I wanna know if possible to create particle objects or objects that will look like a silt and will interact with water simulation?

[image]

Comment: apologies , I only have water simulation that will fall into a container , I want to have also a silt ( sand ) that will float inside the water but I don't know how to create a silt (sand) that will interact with fluid simulation

Comment: I updated the question with an image. As you can see, I made a water flow that will pass through the pipes. However, for the time being, it is just water. I want to add silt to the container so that when the water begins to simulate it, it will interact with the silt like sand and filter the water on the pipes.  I will add some filter aroute the pipes and put some plats for the roots to filter the silt.

Comment: I do not have any idea since I am still a beginner on this platform , i updated the question with image that will see the reference

Comment: basically what I just really want is to create a silt that will interact like floating inside the water